# C# - How to use another project logging configuration into current project?

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender, dmz

I have 12 projects in my solution file. There are most Windows services (`ServiceProj_1, ServiceProj_2, ...`) and one project is of web application (`WebApp`). I use log4net for logging. `WebApp` and `ServiceProject_1, ServiceProj_2, ...` have log4net configuration into `web.config` and `app.config` files respectively. We have implemented a DMZ, so the `WebApp` is only exposed to the other people. Now there is a requirement to use logging of those windows service projects instead of `WebApp`.

I have come to know that I can create a custom appender and make it possible. The catch is, there are lots of lines already written into `WebApp` to log a `LogMessage` into log file so we cannot touch those lines.

I have no idea what to do and how to do. Need help.
If the description is not understandable then please let me know I will try to explain more.

Comment: I edited your question, take a look. It is unclear `at least` to me what you are saying.
I am not sure what your end result needs to be?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the config file and load it dynamically...
Here my config file is found at the location of FullConfigFilePath.

```
private Configuration Config
{
    get
    {
        if (_Config != null) return _Config;

        _Config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(
        new ExeConfigurationFileMap()
        {
            ExeConfigFilename = FullConfigFilePath
        }, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        return _Config;
    }
}
```

Once the config is loaded you can access the values from there....
For instance.....

```
private string BaseUrl
{
    get
    {
        return this.Config.AppSettings.Settings["MyConfigSetting"].Value;
    }
}
```

Hopefully you can tweak and use this sort of approach for your needs.